# Position div at mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a floating DIV with dynamic content like this

```
<div id="rollover" style="display:none;background:#ffff99;width:150px;position:absolute;z-index:9999">
    <div id="rollover_content" style="padding:4px;border:1px solid"></div>
</div>
```

Event handlers fetch relevant content and set the innerHTML of the inner DIV. How can I position the top/left of the div as close as possible to the mouse position?

jQuery is available on the page, if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is the [jQuery UI Position plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Utility/Position).  More info [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Position).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `e` is the parameter in your event handler:

```
$("#rollover").css({left:e.pageX + "px", top:e.pageY + "px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see how to get mouse coordinates: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

From there you can update div absolute positioning to whatever the coords are.